# Secondary workflow did not start in task list

Tags: workflow

The scenario is using incoming email, an item is created in principal list which trigger principal workflow automatically. Then a task item is updated in the task list by the principal workflow. the workflow associated with the task list does not trigger. Both workflows'status was marked as completed and both of them run under system account. What is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run workflows under user account not system account.

Please check below link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-secondary-workflow-6b77ffd5-9ad6-4c20-b5a4-d686e2deafc2

It Says:

> A workflow running under the system account cannot trigger a secondary
>   workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly calling the 2nd workflow from the 1st?

If you set the second workflow up as a 2010 workflow you should be able to call it at the end of the 1st workflow.

You can read more about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx